# Disallow Copy and Paste from outside source

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to disallow pasting into a text editor using the following function.

`$('#textarea').live('paste', function() { return false; });`

This works, I would like to now allow copying and pasting from within the element itself.

Example:
If a write within the editor itself and would like to rearrange the text I can use a Copy and Paste button I created. This works - if the above function is turned off.

Is there a way to disallow outside pasting into an element except for what has been copied and pasted from with an element?

Comment: maybe create an md5 hash of the content being copied, and then check to see if the pasted content = the stored md5 hash

Comment: This may be possible to *some* extent... but why do this in the first place? The limitation is trivial to circumvent in any case.

Comment: Because of the garbage that people paste into editors to post. You can remove majority of it, but it seems people once again try to find a way to break it - just into inject what isn't allowed.

Comment: How can I eliminate anything like this getting inputted or pasted into the text editor.

<script src="" type="text/javascript"></script>

People copy and paste the strangest things, and they do not realize what gets carried over.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this... this will disable the context menu...

```
onload=function(){
document.oncontextmenu=function(){return false;}
}
```

but, if the user knows what they're doing they can probably get around this.